# How do you export/import/copy pages from 2019 to Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, 2019

I'm facing a problem:
I need to transfer (copy) a couple of pages from Sharepoint 2019 to Sharepoint Online. I tried doing this with the help of Sharegate. It manage to copy my pages to SPO, but when I try to open these pages in SPO, I get an "Unexpected error".

I might have a clue why this happens. There is some custom code on the pages I copy, and I believe SPO can't open these pages properly because of this.

I've also tried doing this with the help of PnP, using the Export-PnpClientSidePage - but it seems this is not supported in Sharepoint 2019?

My question is - is it possible to maybe strip custom code with the help of Sharegate? If the Export-PnpClientSidePage would work I could strip code in the XML... any other ideas or thoughts?

Comment: Any additional error message other than "Unexpected Error"? Maybe some screenshot to elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

*My question is - is it possible to maybe strip custom code with the help of Sharegate? If the Export-PnpClientSidePage would work I could strip code in the XML... any other ideas or thoughts?*

Well, it seems to me that the migration was done successfully although having an issue with the page. You'll need to open up the page in the destination (Online) that is throwing an error with SharePoint Designer 2013 and strip the custom code manually.
If it's an aspx page, you'll need to look at references for custom web parts or controls/components inside and remove it. Sharegate can't strip this as the whole aspx body is considered as "content".

Answer (score 0):

Just want to give a heads up: We ended up in transfer the pages manually. There was too much custom code in the pages, and too much work fixing them :(